# Convergence almost sure

Tags: probability

For a sequence of random variables $\{ {X_n},n \ge 1\} $ , let $P({X_n} = {2^n}) = \frac{1}{{{4^n}}} = P({X_n} =  - {2^n}),P({X_n} = 0) = 1 - \frac{2}{{{4^n}}}$

(1) Show that ${X_n}\mathop  \to \limits^{a.s} 0$

Solution:   $P(|{X_n} - 0| \ge \varepsilon )$    =$P(|{X_n}| \ge \varepsilon )$
            = $P({X_n} \ge \varepsilon ) + P({X_n} \le  - \varepsilon )$
            = $P({2^n} \ge \varepsilon ) + P( - {2^n} \le  - \varepsilon )$
            = $\frac{1}{{{4^n}}} + \frac{1}{{{4^n}}}$

= $\frac{2}{{{4^n}}}$

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {P(|{X_n} - 0| \ge \varepsilon )} $=$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {P(|{X_n}| \ge \varepsilon )}  
= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{{4^n}}}}  < \infty $

Then ${X_n}\mathop  \to \limits^{a.s} 0$

This Method it True or False

(2) Show $\dfrac{{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k }}{{\sqrt n }}\mathop  \to \limits^p 0$

How can I show ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to prove the first statement is ok, but you need to remove things like $P(2^n < \epsilon)$

$P(|{X_n} - 0| \ge \varepsilon ) =P(|{X_n}| \ge \varepsilon) = P({X_n} \ge \varepsilon ) + P({X_n} \le  - \varepsilon )\leq \frac{1}{{{4^n}}} + \frac{1}{{{4^n}}}$

For the second one, use [Markov inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality):

$P(|\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k}{\sqrt{n}}| > \epsilon)  \leq  \dfrac{E|\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k}{\sqrt{n}}|}{\epsilon} \leq  \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n E|X_k|}{\sqrt{n}\epsilon}  = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}}{\sqrt{n}\epsilon}$